# Help Identify this Specialized Bike - Allez?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

Apparently this is a 2012 Specialized Allez Comp in Size 52. I cannot find any Allez models matching this photo. It claims to be Shimano 105. Any ideas? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It looks totally legitimate. It's a small size and could be in the "lady" colourway. Quite common to have the same bike in different colours for F & M for that era, just the ladies' often had blue/pink/flowers and was available in a smaller size with a different saddle.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the feedback. It does look like a lady colourway.

Answer (score 2):

The frame and wheels do look like the Specialized Allez Sport as shown on Specialized’s website (just with a slightly different paint job):

[image]

https://www.specialized.com/de/de/allez-sport/p/49774?color=149431-49774

The one in the link has a cheap Shimano Sora groupset.

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [2012 Allez](https://issuu.com/pardorf/docs/spc-redbook-2012-e) lineup:

[image]

I don't see a ladies Allez in the catalog.
For 2012 it does not look like the right decal scheme.

Comment: The ladies' version was called Dolce, not sure if Specialized do ladies models of bikes nowadays

Comment: @Swifty I don't know about other models, but I'm pretty sure they're still making the Ruby (women's version of the Roubaix).